What is the formal adjoint of Hessian?
How one can calculate the formal adjoint of the Hessian? More precisely, let $M$ be a compact Riemannian manifold, $f \in C^\infty(M) $ a function and $A \in \Gamma(T^*M \otimes T^*M)$ a $(2,0)$-tensor. What is the function $\text{Hess}^*(A)$ such that
$$ \int_M \langle \text{Hess} f, A \rangle \; = \int_M f \text{Hess}^*(A) \tag 1$$
Here is my attempt
\begin{align}
\langle \text{Hess} f, A \rangle &= (\text{Hess} f)_{ij} A_{kl} g^{ik}g^{jl} \tag 2 \\
(\text{Hess} f)_{ij} &= \partial_i \partial_jf - (\nabla_{\partial_i}\partial_j)f \tag 3
\end{align}
Integrating by parts one can check that for any vector field $ X $ and functions f and g,
$$\int_M gXf = -\int_M f[ Xg + g \text{Div}(X) ] $$
Substituting (2) and (3) in (1) and applying the previous integration by parts multiple times,
\begin{align}
\int_M \langle \text{Hess} f, A \rangle = \int_M f[ &\partial_i \partial_j A^{ij} + \partial_j A^{ij} \text{Div}(\partial_i) + A^{ij} \partial_j \text{Div}(\partial_i) + \partial_i A^{ij} \text{Div}( \partial_j) \\
+ &A^{ij} \text{Div}(\partial_i) \text{Div}(\partial_j) + (\nabla_{\partial_i}\partial_j)(A^{ij}) + A^{ij} \text{Div}(\nabla_{\partial_i}\partial_j) ]
\end{align}
I guess I found one local expression for $\text{Hess}^*(A)$. For me it is not completely clear that $\text{Hess}^*(A)$ exist. I could verify that such local expression is invariant by coordinates but I bet there is a better way. Is there a better local expression or a global expression? Maybe there is supposing $A$ symmetric?
It would be nice to see a global expression or another attempt to calculate $\text{Hess}^*(A)$. Thanks in advance for any help.

Does it help to write the Hessian as $\nabla(df)$, with $\nabla$ the induced connection on $T^*M$?

When you write down and integral, you should include the $dV_g$ (which is well defined independent of coordinates) or $dx^1\cdots dx^n$ (which depends on the coordinates used),

@TedShifrin Thanks for your suggestion! I'm not sure how to use it though.

I suggest doing this into two steps. First, observe that the Hessian is the covariant derivative of a $(1,0)$-tensor $df$. I prefer to think of it as a $(2,0)$-tensor, $$ (\operatorname{Hess}f)(X,Y) = ( \nabla df)(X,Y). $$ Let $\omega$ be a $(1,0)$ tensor. First prove that given a $(0,2)$-tensor $A$,, $$ \int_M \nabla_i\omega_jA^{ij},dV_g = -\int_M \omega_j\nabla_iA^{ij},dV_g. $$ Next, observe that $\nabla_iA^{ij}\partial_j$ is a vector field. Prove that given a vector field $V$ and a function $f$ that $$\int_M \partial_ifV^i,dV_g = -\int_Mf\nabla_iV^i,dV_g.$$

It’s a double divergence. This follows from the ‘fact’ that the formal adjoint of a single covariant derivative is negative of divergence, so since $\text{Hess}=\nabla\nabla$, the formal adjoint is $(-1)^2\text{div}\circ\text{div}$ (the two $\text{div}$’s act on different spaces of course).
First a precise definition:

Definition (Generalized divergence).
Let $(M,g)$ be semi-Riemannian. Let $(E,\pi,M)$ be a vector bundle and let $\nabla$ be any connection on $\text{Hom}(TM;E)$. Define the generalized divergence operator $\text{div}_{g,\nabla}:\Gamma(\text{Hom}(TM;E))\to\Gamma(E)$ as
\begin{align}
\text{div}_{g,\nabla}(\zeta):=\text{tr}_g(\nabla\zeta)=g^{ij}(\nabla_{e_i}\zeta)(e_j),
\end{align}
where $\{e_1,\dots, e_n\}$ is any local frame for $TM$. So, $\text{div}_{g,\nabla}$ is a first order differential operator $\text{Hom}(TM;E)\to E$.

In practice, the way we get a connection in $\text{Hom}(TM;E)$ is by starting with connections in $TM$ and $E$ and putting them together. Furthermore, since we wish to discuss formal adjoints, we need bundle metrics in $TM$ (i.e a semi-Riemannian metric on $M$) and a bundle metric on $E$, and ideally we should consider metric-compatible connections on $TM$ and $E$.

Lemma.
Let $(E,\pi,M)$ be a vector bundle. Suppose $M$ has a semi-Riemannian metric $g$ and equip it with the Levi-Civita connection $\nabla^g$. Suppose $E$ has a non-degenerate bundle metric and a metric-compatible connection $\nabla^E$ on $E$. Let $\nabla=\text{Hom}(\nabla^g,\nabla^E)$ be the induced connection on $\text{Hom}(TM;E)$.
Then, the formal adjoint of $\nabla^E$ viewed as a first order differential operator $E\to \text{Hom}(TM;E)$ is the first order differential operator $-\text{div}_{g,\nabla}$ from $\text{Hom}(TM;E)\to E$, as defined above.

Finally, in the case where $E$ is some tensor bundles (e.g $T^*M$ or $T^*M\otimes T^*M$), we only need to start with a semi-Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, then use the respective connections induced by the Levi-Civita connection on $TM$.

Edit: Proof of Lemma.
The proof is a simple matter of applying the product rule and metric-compatibility of $\nabla^E$. Let $X,Y$ be vector fields on $M$ and $\phi\in\Gamma(E)$ $\Phi\in\Gamma(\text{Hom}(TM;E))$, and for notational convenience, define the $1$-form $\omega$ on $M$ by
\begin{align}
\omega(\cdot)&:=\langle\Phi(\cdot),\phi\rangle_E.
\end{align}
Henceforth, I’ll denote all the connections as $\nabla$ and let you figure out which ones I mean.
\begin{align}
(\nabla_X\omega)(Y)&=\nabla_X\left(\omega(Y)\right)-\omega(\nabla_XY)\\
&:=\nabla_X\bigg(\left\langle\Phi(Y),\phi\right\rangle_E\bigg)-\omega(\nabla_XY)\\
&=\left\langle\nabla_X\left(\Phi(Y)\right),\phi\right\rangle_E
+\left\langle\Phi(Y),\nabla_X\phi\right\rangle_E-\omega(\nabla_XY)\\
&=\left\langle(\nabla_X\Phi)(Y),\phi\right\rangle_E+\underbrace{\langle\Phi(\nabla_XY),\phi\rangle_E}_{=\omega(\nabla_XY)}
+\left\langle\Phi(Y),\nabla_X\phi\right\rangle_E-\omega(\nabla_XY)\\
&= \left\langle(\nabla_X\Phi)(Y),\phi\right\rangle_E
+
\left\langle\Phi(Y),\nabla_X\phi\right\rangle_E.
\end{align}
The first, third and fourth lines just used the appropriate product rule/commuting with contractions. Also, in going from the second to third equal sign, I used that $\nabla^E$ and $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_E$ are compatible. This is an equality of $(0,2)$ tensor fields on $M$; we can now take the trace relative to $g$ of both sides to get
\begin{align}
\text{div}(\omega)&=\langle\text{div}_{g,\nabla}\Phi,\phi\rangle_E+\langle\Phi,\nabla\phi\rangle_{\text{Hom}(TM,E)},
\end{align}
where on the LHS by the divergence of a $1$-form, I mean the divergence of the metrically-related vector field. Now, if we take $\Phi,\phi$ such that atleast one of them has compact support, and we integrate over $M$ then the LHS integrates to $0$ (if $\partial M$ is empty, otherwise it gives a boundary flux), thereby proving that the formal adjoint of $\nabla^E$ is $-\text{div}_{g,\nabla}$.

Thank you for you answer! Could you provide a reference? I'm working to understand better right now

@TryingToLearn honestly i don’t have one. I just know from some lectures in my PDE class the definition of formal adjoints, and that (for the scalar case) the formal adjoint of the gradient is (minus) divergence (obviously by the divergence theorem). Then I just worked out the necessary generalization.

Then it would be nice to see some steeps of the proof

@TryingToLearn I’ve added the proof. It’s just the ‘product rule’ and being careful.
